# How to dump dict(key with multiple list) to csv using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have dictionary like

```
my_dict={
"A": [["value-1", "value-2"], [1, 2]],
"B": [["price-1", "price-2"], [1,2]]
}
```

I want to `dump` this dictionary with pandas into `csv` file

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=my_dict, orient='index')
df.to_csv("data/mydict_11sept.csv", sep=',')
```

**output:**

```
           A           |       B
________________________________________________    
["value-1", "value-2"] | ["price-1", "price-2"]
       [1, 2]          |     [1,2]
```

**expected Output:**

```
    A       |    B
-----------------------
value-1 | 1 | price-1 | 1
value-2 | 2 | price-2 | 2
```

**Updated: output of my file is given and expected file format is given**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preprocessing first in dict comprehension with `enumerate`:

```
d = {f'{k}_{i}': x for k, v in my_dict.items() for i, x in enumerate(v)}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
       A_0  A_1      B_0  B_1
0  value-1    1  price-1    1
1  value-2    2  price-2    2
```

EDIT:

```
d = {k:list(zip(*v)) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print (df)
              A             B
0  (value-1, 1)  (price-1, 1)
1  (value-2, 2)  (price-2, 2)
```

Or:

```
d = {k:[', '.join(str(y) for y in x) for x in zip(*v)] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print (df)
            A           B
0  value-1, 1  price-1, 1
1  value-2, 2  price-2, 2
```

EDIT1: Here is possible create `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
d = {(k, i) : x for k, v in my_dict.items() for i, x in enumerate(v)}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
         A           B   
         0  1        0  1
0  value-1  1  price-1  1
1  value-2  2  price-2  2
```

And if necessary, remove second level, but not recommended, because problem selectin by columns names only one column:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)
print (df)
         A  A        B  B
0  value-1  1  price-1  1
1  value-2  2  price-2  2

print (df['A'])
         A  A
0  value-1  1
1  value-2  2
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to merge?

Comment: @R.A.Munna - Can you explain more?

Comment: In the question first row is merge with corresponding list. Thank you.

Comment: @R.A.Munna - added 2 new solutions - first for tuples, second for joined values to strings

Comment: it's work but I have wanted about the firs row merge and the corresponding list will be in separated column. But your output is in the same column `touple or string`.  Please look I have updated the question with formatting. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199344/discussion-between-jezrael-and-r-a-munna).